# C++ ReadFile crash issue

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I've got the following code:

```
HANDLE hFile = CreateFileA(path, GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, NULL,
    OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL); 
std::cout << "File Handle: " << hFile << std::endl;

DWORD fileSize = GetFileSize(hFile, NULL);
PVOID fileBuffer = VirtualAlloc(NULL, fileSize, MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_READWRITE);
if (!fileBuffer) std::cout << "Couldn't allocate memory " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
// Read the DLL
if (!ReadFile(hFile, fileBuffer, fileSize, NULL, NULL)) std::cout << "Failed to read file " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
```

I get an access violation(0xC0000005) in KernelBase.dll each time I call ReadFile. 
Also, CreateFile shows

```
File Handle: 0000000000000040
```

all the time, I'm not too sure if that's normal a normal handle or not.

[Full Code, with error from debugger, VS2017](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jn9FZ.png)

Edit: If I print the file size, it shows 18.

Comment: That code works fine for me to read a 160MB or so file. You might show a complete example in case the error is in the code you have not shown.

Comment: I tried executing only the code that I posted above from the main function(without anything else) and it still crashes

Comment: Post full code and any errors you get as text in the body of the question.

Comment: I just posted a screenshot 5mins ago of the full program.

Comment: Also, have your code print the result from `GetFileSize`

Comment: It prints out 18

Comment: Check if fileBuffer is NULL.

Comment: The code as posted works. I suspect there's something else causing memory corruption before this block of code run. OP should post entire program.

Comment: Also, the program above will actually continue onto to the next line even when one of those API calls fail. It's entirely possible (although I doubt it), that that std::cout completed and the program crashed on the subsequent line because of a null ptr or bad handle.

Comment: Text files are subject to line ending translation. I'm not sure if CreateFile/ReadFile operate in strictly binary mode to prevent that.  Try a different file. What is the length if you look at the properties in Explorer?

Comment: code nit: Don't put the statement on the same line as `if`.  Always use separate lines - it's much easier to debug that way!

Comment: @RetiredNinja - CreateFile and ReadFile are binary i/o only.

Comment: @selbie I figured they were.  I have no issues reading various text files using this code either.

Comment: Also, the `GetLastError()` call in the middle of a std::cout stream operation is inherently unreliable. The "last error" could easily get reset as a result of the stream operator processing the literal string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From MSDN documentation of ReadFile:

> lpNumberOfBytesRead [out, optional]
>
> A pointer to the variable that
>   receives the number of bytes read when using a synchronous hFile
>   parameter. ReadFile sets this value to zero before doing any work or
>   error checking. Use NULL for this parameter if this is an asynchronous
>   operation to avoid potentially erroneous results. **This parameter can
>   be NULL only when the lpOverlapped parameter is not NULL**. For more
>   information, see the Remarks section.

Try this:

```
DWORD read;
if (!ReadFile(hFile, fileBuffer, fileSize, &read, NULL)) std::cout << "Failed to read file " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
```

Comment: Yeah, I just saw that and revoked my comment. It doesn't cause any issues on Windows 10 when it's null.  Maybe the OP is on an older OS that does crash when the byteRead ptr is null... that's just a guess.

Comment: @selbie - yes, in old windows version *ReadFile* write to *lpNumberOfBytesRead* if *lpOverlapped* is 0. begin from 8.1 (or may be 7, I not check now) *ReadFile* check *lpNumberOfBytesRead* for 0 value, and not write to it in this case